# How to stop memory memory leak from Flask and NLTK

Tags: python, performance, memory-leaks, nltk

I'm building a web application using NLTK and Flask. It's just a simple RESTful application I deployed it on heroku everything went well. However, when the server started getting more request I reached the memory limit from heroku which is 1.5GB. So, I'm guessing it's because I'm loading `nltk.RegexpParser` every time the request comes.

This is the code which is really simple.

```
@app.route('/get_keywords', methods=['POST'])
def get_keywords():
    data_json = json.loads(request.data)
    text = urllib.unquote(data_json["sentence"])
    keywords = KeywordExtraction().extract(text)

    return ','.join(keywords)
```

And this is the keyword extraction bit.

```
import re
import nltk

nltk.data.path.append('./nltk_data/')

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

class KeywordExtraction:
    def extract(self, text):

        sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
        sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
        sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]

        grammar = "NP: {}"
        cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
        tree = cp.parse(sentences[0])

        keywords = [subtree.leaves()[0][0] for subtree in tree.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'NP')]
        keywords_without_stopwords = [w for w in keywords if not w in stopwords.words('english')]

        return list(set(keywords_without_stopwords + tags))
```

I'm not sure if it's the problem with my code or Flask or NLTK. I'm pretty new in Python. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

I tested this by blitz.io and after just 250 requests the server blew up and started throwing R15.

Comment: You can make `cp` a static class variable (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python). I doubt that this will fix your problem. YOu can also try this with stopwords.words('english') so that you aren't creating a lot of instances of that list. Then you should only create one KeywordExtractor and use it all the time rather than creating one with every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by caching things:

```
# Move these outside of the class declaration or make them class variables

stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
grammar = "NP: {}"
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
```

This can be sped up a little as well:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse

...

keywords_without_stopwords = ifilterfalse(stopwords.__contains__, keywords)

return list(keywords_without_stopwords + set(tags))  # Can you cache `set(tags`)?
```

I'd also take a look at Flask-Cache in order to memoize and cache functions and views as much as possible.